# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class business.HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to fetch data from table I am using following code to fetch data from db.

```
public List<UserInfoSetting> fetchAll(Long aid) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<UserInfoSetting> obj = null;
        try {
            String hql = "select s from UserInfoSetting s where s.atom.id=:aid ";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("aid", aid);
            obj = query.list();
            tx.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
             if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
              sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
             System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

It is showing following exception

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class business.HibernateUtil
    setting.user.UserCommunicationDao.fetchAll(UserCommunicationDao.java:146)
    setting.user.UserCommunication.fetchAll(UserCommunication.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

How to resolve the above problem

Comment: the execption clearly says that its unable to find the your class HibernateUtil

Comment: and also when you are performing select query why you need transaction commit operation???

Answer (score 0):

This means either you haven't got all the right Hibernate libraries in your class path, or you're not including the classes you've written. If you're coding using Eclipse, find the project settings and add the Hibernate libraries as dependencies for the project.

You will need to add `hibernate-core`, but quite a few others too.

Maven would help...

And it would help you a lot if you changed the name of your `HibernateUtil` class: there is a standard Hibernate class with the same name. Although in principle you can have two classes with the same name but in different packages, it'll be likely to cause confusion. (For instance, it's not entirely clear which one it can't find.)